# Build maven project with using buck

Tags: java, maven, buck

I have a problem with BUCK build tool from facebook, when I test it with my old maven project.

I have sth like this :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr users  259 10-03 19:59 BUCK
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr users  235 10-03 19:56 .buckconfig
drwxr-xr-x  5 piotr users 4096 10-03 19:58 buck-out/
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr users  267 10-03 19:59 BUILD
drwxr-xr-x  2 piotr users 4096 08-11 16:53 configs/
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr users 3988 09-04 11:55 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 piotr users 4096 09-04 17:18 src/
```

cat .buckconfig

```
[java]
    src_roots = /src/main/java/, /src/main/resources/
    source_level = 8
    target_level = 8

[download]
    maven_repo = http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
    in_build = true

[project]
    ignore = .git, target
```

cat BUILD

```
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    main_class = "com.example.daemon.Server",
    runtime_deps = [":main"],
)

java_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = ["@gson//jar"],
```

cat BUCK

```
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    main_class = "com.example.daemon.Server",
    deps = [":main"],
)

java_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = ["//dep:gson"],
)
```

and i try command :

```
buck targets
Not using buckd because watchman isn't installed.
[+] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...0,0s [100%]
BUILD FAILED: Couldn't get dependency '//dep:gson' of target '//:main':
No build file at dep/BUCK when resolving target //dep:gson.
 ✘  ~/p/replication-daemon   :  ➦ 16ae702  ± 
```

How I can add maven repositories to buck project? (like in gson in this case) I'm looking for any examples, but I don't find anything...

I will be gratefull for any answers...

Comment: You don't have a `BUCK` file under `dep`, right?

Comment: Then the answer by @Tommy below is the correct way to resolve this :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [buck fetch](https://buckbuild.com/command/fetch.html), and the [remote_file](https://buckbuild.com/rule/remote_file.html) rule.  Or even better, check the jar into the repository and use the [prebuilt_jar](https://buckbuild.com/rule/prebuilt_jar.html) rule.